# Mod Rewrite Changing Subdomains

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This ought to be easy, I have an AJAX call from a subdomain, which has a subfolder in the file hierarchy.  I want to use Rewrite rule to get out of the subdomain folder.  Here is the rule that is not working:

```
RewriteRule 
http://(.*).thehawksite.com/system/myemailscript.php
http://www.thehawksite.com/system/myemailscript.php [R,L]
```

So if I am at sub1.thehawksite.com, and I call AJAX "/system/myemailscript.php" I want it to go to www.thehawksite.com/system/myemailscript.php" instead of sub1.thehawksite.com/system/myemailscript.php.  The "sub1" subdomain is in a subfolder, so the document root is different.

sub1 folder is inside of www folder (/www/sub1)

sub1.thehawksite.com points to /www/sub1

======================================

So now I have this:

This is not working either:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).hawksite.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} system/myemail.php
RewriteRule system/myemail.php http://www.hawksite.com/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you edit this to make it clearer what the directory structures actually are on disk and what specifically where document roots are pointed? It isn't clear now whether `sub1` lives within the `www` directory.

Comment: The first argument to `RewriteRule` can't be a full URL, it can only be the path (i.e. `system/myemailscript.php`). You have to use `RewriteCond` and `%{HTTP_HOST}` to match against host names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$ 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /system/mymailscript\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.hawksite.com/system/mymailscript.php [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: You are better off putting `^system/mymailscript\.php` in the `RewriteRule` pattern, rather than using a `RewriteCond` directive. However, since this is a _redirect_ to another subdomain, the OP might still have issues with the same-origin policy?

Comment: Will this work with an older server?  The site was built in 2009.

Comment: What does this mean? 

This variable is not supported: %{REQUEST_FILENAME}